# Building a Page Based on Roles in Session from Relational Database in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, authentication, relational-database, roles

I'm new to codeigniter and just about everything at this point, but I have had some success with feeling my way around php, mysql, ci, and web application development in general. Though, I'm kind of stuck at the moment. So, I wanted to throw this out there to get your opinion on what I'm trying to do, hopefully - you can have the patience to get through to understand my problem and have a solution, as I will attempt my best to give you all the details.

First, I am in the process of developing a web application, to help ease the logging of attendance at a certain organization. I created a member table to hold all the members of the organization, a login table to hold the username and password of members' who hold roles in the organization, a role table, to contain the roles held at the organization, and finally a member_role table to account for any member who may have more than 1 role at the organization. (and of course an attendance table, with Foreign Key to member, but that is outside my current question).

MySQL code includes only the pertinent tables: memeber, login, role, and member_role.

```
<!-- language: lang-mysql -->
CREATE TABLE `member` (
    `id`                int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `fname`             varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `lname`             varchar(32) NOT NULL,
     ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `login` (
    `memberid`          int(10) NOT NULL,
    `username`          varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `password`          varchar(32) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`memberid`) REFERENCES member(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `role` (
    `id`            integer(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `role`          varchar(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `member_role` (
    `memberid`      integer(10),
    `roleid`        integer(10),
    `active`        char(1) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`memberid`) REFERENCES member(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`roleid`) REFERENCES role(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So far, I think I did a pretty good job, in defining the database for this purpose. Your opinions here would be good, since I am a novice, I only know what a newbie would know.

Here's the real problem I'm currently having. I've created a user that has 2 roles. I have it properly storing it into a session, an array of a particular member's roles. The session array returns, roleid 1, and roleid 3.

Let's say I have certain buttons or functions assigned to each roleid. For memeberid = 1, I have assigned to him roleid = 1 and roleid = 3, therefor I only want to build a page including only the functions available with roleid = 1 and roleid = 3. Make sense?

This is where I'm stuck, I have the array, but not sure how to build a page for the user. Should I put the code into the controller or the view? and either way, I am not sure how to populate a page of buttons having only those regarding roleid = 1 and roleid = 3. Hmm, I hope you can understand, because that is about the best I think I can make it clear.

If you do understand, please perhaps if you could give an example of what/how I could achieve this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggestion before you try to reinvent the wheel... 
if you are trying to build a hrm application use orangehrm and work on that basis to your own needs.

otherwise use this

```
foreach($rolesarray as $currentrole)
    {
    //if currentrole is x then do that, if y then do different.
    }
```

you can use this everywhere where you need to display multiple buttons, displays etc

Comment: thanks michael, that looks like a nice application, but a couple things. i'm sure i could strip down that orangehrm to some bare bones, which is all i really need, but i wanted to learn the nuts and bolts of codeigniter, i really like the mvc design, and just wanted to try it out. but also, the project, i am working on, is really barebones, and looking for very simple, yet specific actions. but also designing for future scalability. (oh, now i see your 'otherwise', i will try that now) :D

Comment: Haha, i know. i dont know what you have in mind, but first thing that shot through my mind was this sounds like hrm. thats why i posted it. always nice to have for future reference if you ever need such software.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that, I was already pretty much already running that foreach loop, and I guess it just wasn't clicking in my mind, must be all the hours I been working on this so far. But it's now working, but its also not the most elegant solution, I was hoping for.. But, I suppose, when I start adding the css and div and stuff, as well as jquery and what not, it will appear better.. :D

Comment: Well, a foreach loop is pretty much what you need if you wish to display stuff for multiple items based on different requirements in different variables. CSS and an unordered list would be my aproach to display a ’row’ of buttons.

Comment: what you could also do. is make a php nested array which contains all the dar you need. like $buttons[’userbuttons’][1] and $buttons[’actionbuttons’][5] etc to group your buttons in php code, and when its time to display the you just loop through them in the order you want foreach($buttons[’userbutton’] as $button)

Answer (score 0):

The tables seem good to me except I wonder why you are separating the member and login tables. The columns in Login seem to be just additional attributes of each Member record in which case the tables could be merged into one.

Regarding your question on showing the right buttons for a person belonging to groups 1 and 3 -- I think you're getting stuck because you're thinking about creating one static page for a person with this combination (maybe I'm wrong..?). Instead, you create one page that everyone goes to and at the respective areas of the page where permissions are a factor, you put if statements to determine whether to display any given element, piece by piece. For example, you would come to the "Start Time" button and put logic to display as long as member belongs to at least one group. Then you would get to the "Management Dashboard" and only display if member has group 3 (if not, you would skip the element both in the controller and the view). I hope I understood your question properly.

Regarding whether to check for the permissions in Controller or View, the spirit of MVC is to perform this kind of logic in the Controller. In the View, then, you would check whether the controller prepared information for certain areas of the page. If the view doesn't need anything specific prepared by the controller to display an element (i.e. you don't need anything prepared to display a link/button to the Management Dashboard--you simply need to know whether the person is in group 3), you can have the controller set a variable like $display_management_db_button.

Lastly, user authentication is a very common thing to need in any web app, and CodeIgniter packages do exist for user authentication. I've recently come across Ion Auth which seems to be the right mix of lightweight and robust that I'm looking for, but you can search and find many others out there.

-Gus

---

(edit)
Example:

In the controller:

```
if($this->member->has_group(3)) { $display_management_db_button=true; }
else { $display_management_db_button=false; }

$data = array('display_management_db_button' => $display_management_db_button;);

$this->load->view('time_screen', $data);
```

In the view:

```
if($display_management_db_button) { echo '<input type="button" ... />'; }
```

So the logic remains in the controller. Separating the logic becomes more important in maintaining clean code as your program gets more complex.

Comment: Hi Gus, to answer your first question, is that only a small percentage of the members will have access to the application. like 5%, so I didn't want to waste a column with a bunch of nulls in the member table, though, not entirely sure which is actually a better solution there. I suppose time will tell, unless of course you have some experience to enlighten there?
I now currently have the controller setting the session, then loads the view, which the view pulls out the roles, to which, then the if statements loads the buttons. so I got that working, thanks

Comment: "you simply need to know whether the person is in group 3), you can have the controller set a variable like $display_management_db_button." - sounds like an interesting idea, could you give me an example of how/where would i pass that and i guess basically execute that? i only have a vague idea of codeigniter at the moment, been lucky to find some video tutorials that walked me through most of "my" successes.